# Redirect from Activity post to specific canvas (iframe) page

Tags: facebook, redirect

In Facebook, how do I redirect a user from wall/activity post to specific page on my canvas (**iframe**)app?

For example, app posts to user's activity that his/her friend just posted a cake receipt and gives a link to receipt page. So on click one should open this page in the canvas instead of canvased website.

Comment: (if by 'activity' you were referring to Open Graph actions, same theory applies, host the object URLs inside your canvas)

Comment: thanks @lgy, will check and report soon. I was looking for a native Facebook parameter or redirect method, if it exists...